# Creation of TEMPORARY TABLE in Slave Database

Tags: postgresql

I have two *PostgreSQL* database servers. One is the *master* and another is a *slave* server which is in read only mode. I have written a few functions that `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` within the function. Now my question: is it possible to run all of those functions in slave server? If it is possible, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html).

> All such connections are strictly read-only; not even temporary tables may be written

You will want something like slony or bucardo doing trigger-based replication if you want the replica to support write operations.

---

Edit: or, nowadays you can use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logical-replication.html).